# How to style the text with text generated using html codes

Tags: html, css

↑ 2.1

```
<span>&#8593; 2.1</span>
```

The above line was a combination of html symbol and regular text. If I would like to align them with the same height, how would I do it? Here is the jsfiddle. Thanks!
http://jsfiddle.net/RnaKb/

Comment: What do you mean by aligning them with the same height? Do you mean font height, or the heights of characters (glyphs)? Should the arrow be of the same height as the digits (assuming the digits are of equal height)? Then this depends on the font: either select a font where things are that way, or add new markup for the arrow and set its font size suitably.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the css `:before` pseudo-selector, converting #8593 to \2191. You can then fiddle with the css for this content:

```
<span> 2.1</span>

span:before {
    content:'\2191';
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

This is not exactly the same height currently (looks good though!), but could be with a little fiddling. But you would also have to test in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

They are already accessible from within the `<span>` element.

Take a look at the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RnaKb/6/) where i just added a little .css

```
span {
    font-size:24px;
    line-height:27px;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
    background-color:#eef;
}
```

But i understand you think the ↑ arrow symbol is styled differently, but it is not. It was drawn that way. So if you want it vertically aligned to bottom, you will have to enclose it in some individual container witch you will have to work with.

```
<span><span class="your-class-to-ajust-bottom">&#8593;</span> 2.1</span>
```

Here is a working example : [jsFiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/RnaKb/7/)